# Neon intrinsic to prevent overflow by subtracting the minimum element from all elements [no looping]

Tags: c, arm, embedded, intrinsics, neon

I want to figure out a tricky way to prevent overflow while using Neon Intrinsic in C for ARM. Here's the logic performed element by element:

```
min = array[0]
for(i=1;i<64;i++)
{
    if(min > array[i])
    {
        min = array[i];
    }
}
for(i=0;i<64;i++)
{
    array[i] -= min;
}
```

I want an alternative solution, which eliminates the need of element by element operations, by performing operations in SIMD way. Thanks.

NOTE: In my case, I use four vectors of `uint8x16_t` datatype. I want to find a single minimum from them and perform normalization (ie; my array with 64 elements, segmented into four `uint8x16_t` vectors).

Comment: Sort first, and then select `array[0]`. You should probably pick a different variable name, too. `array` is a type in C++11.

Comment: A couple `vmin.u8`, some `vpmin.u8`, a `vdup.8` then `vsub.u8`. Doesn't seem particularly complicated.

Comment: @EOF Can you provide the exact steps? I don't get it.

Comment: Sorting takes `O(n log n)` whereas his unsorted search is just `O(n)`.  This question has an answer with `vmin`; [ARM Neon min and max of arrary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611075/find-minimum-and-maximum-value-of-an-array-using-arm-neon-instructions) just remove the `vmax` lines.  Hopefully subtracting from each element doesn't need to be a question.  There is a short circuit case if you find zero.

Comment: @EOF It worked. Thanks. 1. Use vmin_u8 multiple times to accumulate minimum values in a vector (say a 8x8) 2. Use vpmin_u8 'n' times on same vector - bubble sort (here, n = 8) 3. Use vdup_8(sorted_result[0]) to construct vector with target length  4. Use vsub_u8 to subtract => normalize.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use vmin_u8 multiple times to accumulate minimum values in a vector (say a 8x8)
2. Use vpmin_u8 'n' times on same vector - bubble sort (here, n = 8)
3. Use vdup_8(sorted_result[0]) to construct vector with target length
4. Use vsub_u8 to subtract => normalize.

   – ffox